# Adjoint functor theorem for infinity categories

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, ct.category-theory

In HTT, a version of the adjoint functor theorem for (locally) presentable infinity categories is proven (Corollary 5.5.2.9). Is there a more refined version of this somewhere, which more closely resembles Freyd’s original version? I.e., is there a version for infinity categories which are *not* necessarily (locally) presentable, but requires a solution set condition? If so, a reference would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps one can work this out by oneself? After all, the adjoint functor has always a *canonical* representation as a colimit/limit, and the sole purpose of the solution set condition is to provide a small cofinal subcategory so that the colimit/limit exists. So then one has to look for the appropriate notions for $\infty$-categories.

Comment: I agree with you in principle Martin. However, I still haven't figured out how to prove this question (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97562/a-slicker-proof-that-an-object-must-be-initial) in the infinity context, and the classical way to prove the adjoint functor theorem uses this result for 1-categories. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general adjoint functor theorem didn't exist in the literature when this question was originally asked, but now it does: [Nguyen, Raptis, and Schrade](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01664).